# Change array value in a file

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am having a php file that it returns an array. I can get the array values using

```
Config::get('app.timezone');
```

However, I don't know how to replace a value in the array with php.
Is there any easy way to do that?

app.php:

```
<?php
    return array('timezone' => 'value');
?>
```

Comment: You mean replace permanently or at runtime?

Comment: replacing the array value permanently inside the file

Comment: Well just open the file and change the value?

Comment: for to change at runtime ?

Comment: Ah you want to update the value programmatically, through a settings panel or something?

Comment: is that any easy way like Config::get('app.timezone') = 'value';  ??

Comment: You can do `Config::set('app.timezone', 'value')` but that will just change the value for the current request. It won't actually change the file.

Answer (score 1):

To change the value in the Config object, you have to change it with the Config methods because properties are obviously private.

```
Config::set('app.timezone', 'Europe/Brussels');
```

More informations on Laravel : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2